# JavaScript - Timer - Speeding math glitch

Tags: javascript, math, timer, counter

```
    var time_gone = 0

    function timer() {
        time_gone += 0.01 
        console.clear()
        console.log(time_gone)
        setTimeout("timer()", 10)
    }

    timer()
```

Try using this code and look in the console

Why does the counter fail?!?!?!?

Comment: It gives me like 2.320000000000023

Answer (score 1):

This is probably going to get closed as a duplicate, because that's just how JavaScript math works. Actually, most programming languages deal with floating-point numbers like that, so I suggest you really read [the post linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken), and try to understand it.

Now, to fix the display of the numbers, you can use `toFixed`:

```
var time_gone = 0;
function timer() {
    time_gone += 0.01;
    console.clear();
    console.log(time_gone.toFixed(2));
    setTimeout(timer, 10);
}
timer();
```